# Socket or Surface Mount Adapter? (SOP16 to DIP16)

Tags: adapter, packages, socket, sop

I'm looking to use a [HX711 chip](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/ForceFlex/hx711_english.pdf) (which says it's a SOP-16L package,) and attach it to a circuit on a breadboard.

I've found two ways to do so: a [socket](https://www.ebay.com/itm/165242379643?hash=item2679369d7b:g:B5MAAOSwnBJhwCb%7E) or just the [adapter](https://www.ebay.com/itm/220940538083?hash=item33711510e3:g:ZrUAAOSw4A5Yp8mt).

Is there any difference between the two, other than that the adapter requires soldering?

I'm leaning towards the socket, since I barely have any experience soldering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major difference is the soldering as you mentioned.

The socket would allow you to replace the IC quickly - such sockets are used for testing of IC's for instance.

The soldered adapter could give lower contact resistance and maybe a bit less capacitance in total but I think it would not matter much.

I wonder though why you did not buy a HX711 readily assembled on a board with blocking capacitors and so on. For instance sparkfun offers a "SparkFun Load Cell Amplifier - HX711". There are a lot of modules around and you might find one where the pin headers are pre-soldered - so everything ready for breadboard.

Soldering of pin headers to such board might be a good starter to train soldering skills - it's not that magic really :)

Comment: Yeah, the project I'm using the HX711 for has prohibited daughterboards like the Sparkfun one, but thanks anyways